# Batch file to copy files based on filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to use a batch file to copy files in a directory based on filename.

For example: These are the files in a particular directory.

```
XXXXX_2013-08-20_S01_R0.txt
XXXXX_2013-08-20_S02_R0.txt
XXXXX_2013-08-20_S03_R0.txt
XXXXX_2013-08-20_S04_R0.txt
XXXXX_2013-08-20_S05_R0.txt
```

If i use the following command

```
copy /b *.txt TESTING.txt
```

It doesn't copy the files based on FILENAME. I want to copy files based on the filename
like this

```
COPY /b XXXXX_2013-08-20_S01_R0.txt+XXXXX_2013-08-20_S02_R0.txt+XXXXX_2013-08-20_S03_R0.txt+XXXXX_2013-08-20_S04_R0.txt+XXXXX_2013-08-20_S05_R0.txt TESTTING.TXT
```

How can I automate this?
I don't want to manually type in the filename and then combine them.

Comment: I don't quite understand fully.  Are the files you're wanting to copy specifically binary files?  My testing here, on some ASCII text files I made up, had your supplied command `copy /b *.txt test.txt` work.  The resulting file was the contents of my test files concatenated together.

Answer (score 0):

The copy command will progress via filename in an NTFS formatted drive.

FAT32 will advance by position in the FAT, which is not sorted.

Comment: @downvoter : foxidrive is quite correct. OP should state what happened, not tell us that what was expected didn't happen and leave us to guess. The fact that what was expected didn't happen is obvious. Had it happened, there would be no reason to post a question.